# Добавление сгруппированных значений из БД в массив

Tags: php, sql

Сгруппировал значения БД по полю "Профиль".

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT profile FROM list GROUP BY profile");
while($massive = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $myrow['profile']; 
}
?>
```

Теперь в результате у меня выводятся 2 сгруппированных значения: "Менеджмент" и "Психология" (к примеру).
Нужно создать массив и добавить туда эти значения. Но никак не получается у меня это реализовать. Пробовал так:

```
$mas[] =  $massive['profile'];
```

но в массив добавляется только первый элемент.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял поставленную задачу, то попробуйте так:
`foreach($massive as $v){ 
$mas[]=$v['profile']; 
}`

Answer (score 2):

Если ты перестанешь путаться в именах переменных и один раз напишешь этот код правильно, то все получится.

Кстати, про mysql функции надо было давно забыть.
и писать так:

```
$sql     = "SELECT profile FROM list GROUP BY profile";
$profile = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```